# Replacing a string in HTML file in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace a string stored in a list with an HTML tag in a file by doing:

```
    links=[<a href="http://hexagon-dashboard-gbc-01/vboard/latest?regs=3281546">http://hexagon-dashboard-gbc-01/vboard/latest?regs=3281546<!--V68NUR--></a>]
   str1="""<a href="%s">%s<!--V68NUR--></a>"""%(vboard['V68N']['perf.tl'],vboard['V68N']['perf.tl'])
     with open(html_file,'r+') as f:
                content = f.read()
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                f.write(content.replace(links[0],str1))
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not Tag.

What am I missing? Please help me with the modification I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

From what you posted, I suppose you are treating a html file as plain text and going to perform string replacement.

The replace() function only works when both of its arguments are strings.

The reason you got an error is that links[0] is not a string but a tag.

If you manage to get links like this (note the single quotes)

```
links=['<a href="http://hexagon-dashboard-gbc-01/vboard/latest?regs=3281546">http://hexagon-dashboard-gbc-01/vboard/latest?regs=3281546<!--V68NUR--></a>']
```

then

```
content.replace(links[0],str1)
```

would not produce any errors.

To edit html files, you can also use [HTML Parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) instead.

Comment: links is also obtained from html

Comment: Thanks@Steven Liang